# Identifier expected,String is a keyword

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a php code like this,going to convert it in to C#.

```
function HuntingDate()
{
    Global $nameofselectbox,$startYear,$endYear,$year,
    $startDate,$endDate,$startMounth,$endMounth,$startDay,$endDay;
    $today = getdate();
    $year=$today['year'];
    $mounth=$today['mon'];
    $day=$today['mday'];
```

Here is my try( I tried to use enum for this)

```
public enum  HuntingDate{string StartYear,string EndYear,string Year,string StartDate,string EndDate,string StartMonth,string EndMonth,stirng StartDay,string EndDay}
```

Can i do thisone with enum ? i got the error "Identifier expected,String is a keyword"

Comment: What's this `stirng StartDay`...

Comment: Why is everything a `string` ? You have so many interesting data-types available... Also, this doesn't seem to be anything to do with an `enum`. It might be that you have misunderstood the `enum` keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No not with [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you should use a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b0thckt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for this:

```
public class HuntingDate
{
    string StartYear;
    string EndYear;
    string Year;
    string StartDate;
    string EndDate;
    string StartMonth;
    string EndMonth;
    string StartDay;
    string EndDay;
}
```

you then have further things to consider:

1. Strings are not ideal for date type data, for this consider using [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) - with this you can merge the year, month and day values into one [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

   ```
   public class HuntingDate
   {
       public DateTime StartDateTime;
       public DateTime EndDateTime;
   }
   ```
2. Classes are used to define the structure of an object, as my example stands you would need to [create an instance of the class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in order to use it:

   ```
   HuntingDate huntingDate = new HuntingDate();
   ```

   with this you have to consider where you want to have access to it. If you need a global accessible instance you could initialise the class at a global scope level, or consider using a [static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (though it should be noted that these values would be persisted across the whole application):

   ```
   public static class HuntingDate 
   {
       public static string Something;
   }
   ```
3. I would strongly suggesting doing some reading on C# (get [a book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book)!) if you want to do this more seriously you should get a solid grasp of the basics of C#

Comment: then it should be Public class HuntingDate(){ StartYear datetime} am i correct ?

Comment: @ChathuraRanasinghe: Not sure what you mean? Have edited point 1 as my best guess at what your question is

Answer (score 1):

> **No**, You can do this with enum. By default the underlying type of each element in the enum is int.
>   You can specify another `integral numeric` type by using a colon, as
>   shown in the example below. For a full list of possible types, see enum (C#
>   Reference).

Example:

```
enum Months : byte { Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec };
```

You can use [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx) type for this purpose.

```
public struct HuntingDate
{
    int StartYear;
    int StartMonth;
    int StartDay;         
    int Year;             
    DateTime StartDate;  // it smells like you are storing date then why do 
                         // you not use DateTime rather than these..   
    DateTime EndDate;
    int EndYear;
    int EndMonth;        
    int EndDay;
}
```

If your `Year` it not necessary then it can be shorten as:

```
public struct HuntingDate
{
  public DateTime StartDate;                         
  public DateTime EndDate;
}
```

other wise go for the full values including `Year`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the (string) values "StartYear", "EndYear" and so on as values of an enum.
You cannot do that: an enum is always based on some integer type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better off using the DateTime type for the start and end dates, and wrap it all in a class something like this:

```
public class HuntingDate
{
    public HuntingDate(DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        _start = start;
        _end   = end;
    }

    public DateTime End
    {
        get
        {
            return _end;
        }
    }

    public DateTime Start
    {
        get
        {
            return _start;
        }
    }

    private readonly DateTime _start;
    private readonly DateTime _end;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

bear i mind i don't know php from... well php...

```
function HuntingDate()
{
    Global $nameofselectbox,$startYear,$endYear,$year,
    $startDate,$endDate,$startMounth,$endMounth,$startDay,$endDay;
    $today = getdate();
    $year=$today['year'];
    $mounth=$today['mon'];
    $day=$today['mday'];

   ... rest of code
}
```

I'm guesstimating you'll need a class (and not an [enum](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203225/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/042804-1.aspx))

```
  public class HuntingDate()    
  {
     string NameOfSelectbox;
     DateTime endDate;

     rest of code ...
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I saw there are lots of answers,WHAT IS THE BEST ANSWER ?

Comment: still i'm trying to do oneby one,If anyone can you tell me WHich is the bstone i can directly try it out,anyway i'll try and notify here